# Matrix special multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multiplication

I have two array m1 and m2 and I want to make a special multiplication :
1*8 + 2*6, 3*8 + 4*6, 1*2 + 2*6, 3*2 + 4*6, ...
So I want this output. result = [20, 48, 14,30,..]

```
m1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
m2 = np.array([8,6,2,6,2,5])
```

I'm sorry but I don't really know how to do that.
I think with a for loop like this:

```
for x in m1:
```

Thank you

Comment: Why did you stop after - `for x in m1:`?

Comment: I don't know what to do after for x in m1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So obviously, your scalar products must be done 2 by 2, so you need to start reshaping your data:

```
m1 = np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape(2,2)
m2 = np.array([8,6,2,6,2,5]).reshape(3,2)
```

So now, you want the dot product of on the last column, and flatten the result, so do:

```
np.dot(m2, m1.T).reshape(-1)
```